# Screen capture Flash Player movie

Tags: c#, screen-capture

`WM Capture` is a software that can capture Flash Player content even if the browser window is hidden.

How does this work? Can I reproduce that in C# by hooking DirectDraw or something else?

[image]

Comment: I suppose even Flash player uses DirectShow, so I'd say you can if you add a custom filter (that will actually do the capture) in the filter schema defined by flash in DirectShow (Actually this would only work if you're trying to capture something from a flash video)

Comment: DirectShow filter may be a good starting point. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it actually captures video -it may just pick the cache from Flash Player. When you play a video it gets buffered, so if your program manages to find out where is the buffer stored, you could pick the video, maybe even when the browser is closed.

There are several programs that work like this, for example: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html

Comment: Yes it really capture the movie from Flash Player on-screen content (not cache). I updated my question and while the Show/Hide button hides the browser, the thumbnail displays the invisible movie.